# Moved /lib64 to /backup_lib64 using sudo, now sudo doesn't work on CentOS6.4

Tags: linux, sudo, centos-6

I did

```
sudo mv /lib64 /backup_lib64
```

to test some compilation. Now sudo doesn't work at all

```
farhat@heracles:~/software/sudo-1.8.7$ sudo ls
sudo: unable to dlopen /usr/libexec/sudoers.so: (null) 
sudo: fatal error, unable to load plugins
```

How can I move `backup_lib64` to `lib64` without rebooting the system? I do not have the root password either.

Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you didn't get much in terms of a ways out of this situation. However, have you tried `su` command? Perhaps it doesn't need to load any libraries (not likely, but you could still try).

Comment: su works, unfortunately you still need the root password.

Comment: Well, then I'm sorry to tell you, but it seems like you have to pull some other triggers there... it doesn't look like there's a technical way to solve this.

Comment: I figured out the root password finally. Things are okay now.